# Java EE Service dependencies

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I hope this question is not too abstract. This is about Java EE architecture or design of Services.
I have two business logics (simplified here for ease of reading):

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class EmailService {

  @EJB
  private SomeBean someBean;
  // ... some other EJBs to acces the DB layer (and using JPA)

  public void sendEmail(String recipient /* some parameters */) {
     // ... some email sending logic here

  }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ExecutePaymentService {

  @EJB
  private UserBean userBean;
  // ... some other EJBs to acces the DB layer (and using JPA)

  public void executePayment(int amount, int userId) {
     // ... some payment logic here
     // NEED TO SEND EMAIL HERE
  }
}
```

The design I have is that the JSF Managed Beans are calling the above services. My issue is that the Managed Beans contain some logic:
- execute the payment
- IF payment is successful send email
- IF not do something else

I want to have this logic in the Service EJBs so the Managed Beans are only gathering input and returning result.

The other options is that `ExecutePaymentService` extends `EmailService` then call the sendEmail stuff. This can lead to a huge inheritance tree to be able to provide any service from any service, harder to maintain on long run and big application.... Since most of the services need to have EJB injected to access database I can't use non-EJB services....

What would be a better way to allow a `service to call another service`?

Comment: If you have the chance to use an ESB this choice logic can be implemented using a tool like Drools. The business logic presented is somewhat related to Factory pattern, if defined a 'type of service' enum. You could declare an interface with common methods and use a class with @WebService(endpointInterface="package.MyPaymentInterface").

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't think we can implement ESB at this stage, but I will keep it as an option when we need a new platform.

Comment: A small suggestion: you don't need the `@LocalBean`. It's very tempting to put one there, but if absolutely does nothing in your situation; a stateless bean without a business interface already automatically exposes a no-interface view, which is exactly what `@LocalBean` is used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask yourself wether ExecutePaymentService IS an Email Service. 
Maybe email service is just one of the functionalists you need? 
Why not inject the Email service to the ExecutePaymentService? 
My answer can be applied to other means , such as WebSerivces (which can be implemented using EJBs), 
 this is more like a classic Object Oriented design, than really a Java technical design question, and once you understand if ExecutePaymentService is in its base an EmailService (I have a feeling the answer is NO) - 
you will understand how to model better the beans.

Comment: Umm... How are JPA transaction work? If I do some DB edit/create in both services (or more, like we have another logging service that logs special activities in several other services). I have one DB transaction started when I enter the PaymentService EJB method. If I inject a ActivityLoggerService that also needs to edit the DB (and possible some tables common to PaymentService), is there a risk of deadlock or collision or issues? Is it going to run in the same transaction or a different one. I know, I must check by myself too :) I am going to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer led us to a new design, injecting some services, and using simple "helper" objects when no DB interaction needed.